# ¿Cómo puedo crear una función que cree un diccionario de acuerdo a una condición?

Tags: python, lista, filtro

Debo crear una función que tome una lista y compare todos sus elementos entre sí, la condición es, que la diferencia de cada elemento sea menor a una tolerancia definida, una vez se haga la comparación, se crea un diccionario que tome cada elemento como clave y le defina un valor, este valor corresponde al menor número que al ser comparado cumplió la condición, un ejemplo:

lista = [1,3,4,6]

tolerancia = 1

- |1-3| = 2 >= tolerancia (No cumple)
- |1-4| = 3 >= tolerancia (No cumple)
- |1-6| = 5 >= tolerancia (No cumple)
- |3-4| = 1 <= tolerancia (Cumple)
- |3-6| = 3 >= tolerancia (No cumple)
- |4-6| = 2 >= tolerancia (No cumple)

Por lo que el diccionario quedaría algo así

dicc = {
1:1,
3:3,
4:3,
6:6,
}

Tengo un boceto, pero tiene problemas de rango y no sé como corregir o mejorar:

```
def reemplazar_similares(lista1, lista2, lista3, tolerancia=1):
    # Filtrar listas no vacías
    listas = lista1 + lista2 + lista3
    dicc = {}     
    # Verificar si todos los elementos son similares
    for i in range(len(listas)):
        if listas[i]-listas[i+1] <= tolerancia:
            dicc[listas[i]] = min(listas[i], listas[i+1])
        else:
            dicc[listas[i]] = listas[i]
    return (dicc)

lista1 = [1,3]
lista2 = []
lista3 = [4,6]

comparar = reemplazar_similares(lista1, lista2, lista3)
print(comparar)
```

Comment: Buen día @Alejo, te recomiendo leer las secciones [ask] y [tour] para aprender/recordar como funciona el sitio. Las preguntas que no muestran un esfuerzo por parte del autor no se apegan a las normas de la comunidad y por lo tanto terminan cerradas y/o votadas negativamente. Puedes [edit] la pregunta y agregar lo que has intentado o investigado al respecto.

Comment: La he editado, de tal manera que pueda cumplir las normas de la comunidad.

Comment: Y por qué no `dicc = { 1:1, 3:4, 4:3, 6:6, }`? 3 está a 1 unidad de 4 y 4 está a 1 unidad de 3. Tampoco entiendo por qué la función toma 3 listas como parámetro si en la explicación dices que solo trabajas con una.

Comment: Toma 3 listas para sumarlas y hacer la comparación, y dentro del diccionario se le da el valor del número menor de entre los que se restan, o sea para el ejemplo el 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haremos será ordenar la lista.
Así resultará más sencillo encontrar el elemento más pequeño que cumple con la condición de la tolerancia.
Muestro una versión del código que no es óptima, pero es la más sencilla de escribir.
Para listas pequeñas no deberías tener problemas:

```py
def compare_list(numeros: list[int], tolerancia = 1):
    # Ordeno la lista para buscar más rápido
    numeros_ordenados = sorted(numeros)
    resultado = dict()

    # Itero la lista para añadir las llaves al diccionario
    for llave in numeros_ordenados:
        # Itero la lista para añadir los valores al diccionario
        for valor in numeros_ordenados:
            # He encontrado el primer número que cumple la condición
            # Como la lista está ordenada, este es el menor número que cumple la condición
            if abs(llave - valor) <= tolerancia:
                # Añado el valor encontrado al diccionario y salgo del bucle interior
                resultado[llave] = valor
                break

    return resultado
```